# Missing UserIDs

Tags: support, data-explorer, users

I'm working on some performance tests for [my ORM](https://github.com/sproket/PersismPerformance).

I just noticed this with the 2010; these two queries return results.

```
SELECT  distinct UserId FROM Comments WHERE not UserId in (Select ID From Users) order by UserId
SELECT  distinct OwnerUserId FROM Posts WHERE not OwnerUserId in (Select ID From Users) order by OwnerUserId
```

Meaning I have child records pointing to non-existent users.  I know Stack Overflow allows users to be deleted but shouldn't child data also have been removed. Or better, just clear the user fields and set the name to "deleted".

Now I have to make additional tests for integrity for my performance tests.

Comment: Whoops, sorry! Force of habit, I got thrown off by the mention of you making performance tests for your ORM. I'm getting new glasses soon!

Answer (score 4):

What's "the 2010"? A Stack Exchange data dump from 2010?

What you're experiencing might be caused by the backup of the `Users` finishing earlier than the `Comments` and `Posts` table, which are larger. If near the end of the backup a new user joins and posts something, their contribution will be in the `Posts` or `Comments` table but without a matching record in the `Users` table.

That is why [this similar query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1602843) returns results. The one blank record is actually comments by deleted users; these are now owned by [Community](/users/-1).

Comment: Yeah, the StackOverflow2010. It's OK. I'll write the extra tests or change these users to -1